# What is the difference between these two JSON outputs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP and Codeigniter. How to return an array object and not plain array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220656/php-and-codeigniter-how-to-return-an-array-object-and-not-plain-array)

I am stuck here.

What is the different between this:

```
"email": {
  "id": "628",
  "desc": "THIS IS IT",
  "value_1": "THIS IS IT2",
  "value_2": null,
  "value_3": null,
  "value_4": null,
  "privacy": "0"
}
```

And this:

```
"email": [
  {
    "id": "629",
    "desc": "0000",
    "value_1": "0000",
    "value_2": null,
    "value_3": null,
    "value_4": null,
    "privacy": "0"
  }
]
```

How can I get the second one to look like the first one?

**UPDATE**

I am creating the array like this in Codeigniter:

```
array("email" => $result).
```

How can I make it an object instead?