# PHP and Codeigniter. How to return an array object and not plain array?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

In Codeigniter I am creating an array and returning it to the user. I am creating the array like this (result is the return form a DB query):

```
array("email" => $result)
```

Right now it outputs:

```
"email": [
    {
        "id": "629",
        "desc": "0000",
        "value_1": "0000",
        "value_2": null,
        "value_3": null,
        "value_4": null,
        "privacy": "0"
    }
]
```

So `$result` is an array that contains a single object. How can I make `$result` contain just the object instead? Like this:

```
"email": {
    "id": "628",
    "desc": "THIS IS IT",
    "value_1": "THIS IS IT2",
    "value_2": null,
    "value_3": null,
    "value_4": null,
    "privacy": "0"
}
```

Thankful for all input!

Comment: I merged the answers to your older question into this one.  In the future, please edit the original question instead of posting a nearly exact duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use:

```
array("email" => $result->row());
```

See the CI [documentation on queries](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html) and `row()`:

> This function returns a single result row. If your query has more than one row, it returns only the first row. The result is returned as an object.

Comment: or just `array("email" => $result[0])` though that could give undefinex index notices when the result is empty.

Answer (score 1):

The first defines `email` as an *object*.

The second defines `email` as plain array with one item, and that item is an *object* by itself.

For example, to access `id` property using the first form of `email` you should have:

```
var id = obj.email.id;
```

In the second form:

```
var id = obj.email[0].id;
```

Edit: answer to your new question "How can I get the second one to look like the first one" - you can't. The second form is defining whole different thing, you just have to change the way you access that `email` and if always have one item, use `email[0]` like in the above sample code.

Comment: Recommend "object" (the term used in JSON) or "map" rather than "associative array" to avoid confusion.

Comment: I am creating the array like this in Codeigniter: array("email" => $result). How can I make it an object instead?

Comment: Sorry Jonathan, not familiar with CodeIgniter - such question is totally different from your original question.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I will make a new question.

Answer (score 1):

First one is a JSON Object that has a property/member `email` that is, in turn, a JSON Object that contains properties `id`, `desc` etc.

The second one, on the other hand, is a JSON Object that has a property `email` that is a JSON Array that contains **1** element that has properties `id`, `desc` etc.

Basically, if I were to translate the access to the value of `value_1` field:

1 object:

`obj.email.value_1`

2 object:

`obj.email[0].value_1`